# QObject set QList as parent using setParent()

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qlist

I'm trying to use `QObject` tree delete mechanism to delete the list and all `QObject`s that are stored in the list. Qt is still my very week area...

```
QList<QObject*>* list = new QList<QObject*>();
QObject* obj1 = new QObject();
QObject* obj2 = new QObject();
obj1->setParent(obj2);
obj2->setParent((QObject*)list);
```

I got "Segmentation fault" at last line. Can't the `QList` be used as a parent? Doesn't it inherit from `QObject`?

**Edit**:

The main question - is it possible to conveniently delete the list and all list elements without extending the `QList` class? This need to be called by client so it have to be simple.

I would like to simply call:

```
delete list;
```

and not

```
qDeleteAll(list);
delete list;
```

Comment: The biggest question is why are you dynamically allocating the whole list at all. Why it isn't just a ``QList<QObject*> list``?

Comment: Not possible with QList<QObject*> - you could use QSharedPointer though.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `QList` does not inherit from `QObject`.  If you want to delete the contents of the list easily, you can use `qDeleteAll(list)`.

*Edit:*
This is untested, and there may be problems from the base class not having a virtual destructor - but give it ago.

```
template < class T >
class MyList : public QList< T >
{
    static_assert( std::is_pointer< T >::value,
                   "T must be a pointer." );
    //  Constructors...
    ...
    virtual ~MyList() { qDeleteAll( *this ); }
 }
```

Comment: That explains a lot - but still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Remi Actually it answered both of them, but then you edited your question into something completely different.

Comment: That's true - sorry I extended the question after your answers.

Answer (score 0):

option 1)

```
QList<QObject*> list;

.. somewhere in the code

QObject * obj = new QObject();
list << obj;

... 

then 


onDelete() {    // variant 1
       QObject * ptr;
       foreach(ptr, list) {
          delete ptr;
       }
       list(clear);
}

onDelete() { // variant 2
     qDeleteAll(list);
}
```

option 2)

```
 QObject * parent = new QObject();

 somewhere in a code 
 ...
 QObject * child1 = new QObject(parent);
 QObject * child2 = new QObject(parent);


 onDelete() {
     delete parent;   // all children deleted automatically
 }
```

UPD:

From your question update, I can consider that you don't QList at all, just use QObject provided functionality, and if you need children use appropriate childer() method which will give you QList

Comment: I think what you propose 'delete list' is not a good approach at all, i believe that if something allocated within certain module, it should be free'd there. and again, you dont' need a QList _at_all_ QObject maintains list of children itself

Comment: This model is very simplified. I need to create objects in on e module and later, used them and delete in completely different place.

Comment: again, thats not changing an answer, consider some QObject's be a list you are talking about...